# Integrate Mockito with CDI

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, cdi, junit5

I'm currently thinking about expanding unit tests for a server and a client application. Mockito is already in use and - I think - very well suited for the task at hand. However, as the [Mockito documentation](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) itself admits:

> Mockito is not an dependency injection framework, don't expect [the @InjectMocks annotation] to inject a complex graph of objects be it mocks/spies or real objects.

The server-side of course already has CDI via annotations at some places, the client will probably be extended in some place to use CDI for JavaSE in the near future. There is/will be a wild mix of field- and constructor-injection + @postconstruct methods, which is already too complicated for Mockito. So I'm looking for something that will allow me to easily use CDI annotations to inject Mockito's mocks/spies/real objects where needed.

Can Mockito's functionality be expanded via plugins or something similar to enable a dependency resolution closer to what is specified by CDI (I don't think I need the full spec, but something closer to it)? Is there another library that integrates with Mockito and JUnit5 that does that?

Comment: Actual CDI has no place in unit tests. You can use CDI for a more integrated test (eg Spring Integration Tests), but then you start the full context as far as possible in order to test the interaction between the real components. At the "border" of the system, you can use `@MockBean`s.

Comment: CDI can have a place. Of course not for injecting the true dependencies production code would use. That has no place in unit tests as you rightly said. But what I want is different: I want mostly mocks and spies injected (and very rarely actual objects, but those I could do by hand if I need to). Mockito does this to some extend on its own, but it's not very flexible in doing that, e.g. it can't mix constructor injection and field injection. Doing it by hand can require writing a lot of boiler plate code (for example package-private setters for injected fields that are only used in tests)

Comment: If you need to inject a lot, you should reconsider your design, as it's a sign of too many dependencies. As a side note, you should not need to use spies (["real spies should be used carefully and occasionally, for example when dealing with legacy code"](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13)). If you have an example where you need to inject and Mockito falls short, post it.

Comment: Well, yes, "my" design leaves a lot to be desired. It's a couple of million lines of legacy code that has very poor coverage by the existing tests. It would be nice if I could write tests without too many rewrites of the production code and without endlessly adding boilerplate code to the test classes so that I can write more tests for the existing code. The less time I need for each individual test, the more tests I can write during the little breaks between bigger issues. Making a massive refactoring effort will honestly be necessary in the future, but for now it's not feasible.

Comment: „_Making a massive refactoring effort will honestly be necessary in the future, but for now ..._“. Also known as _St. Nimmerleinstag_ in German. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

weld supports this out of the box, specifically by [weld-junit](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit). It supports both [junit4](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit/blob/master/junit4/README.md) and [junit5](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit/blob/master/junit5/README.md). In both cases one can define producer methods for the required injection points in which one can freely use mockito or powermock or any other mocking mechanism to create mocks which weld then injects into the test object.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to mock EJB/CDI beans with OpenEJB, you can do it very easily:
http://tomee.apache.org/master/examples/rest-applicationcomposer-mockito.html

Answer (score 0):

cdi-unit and ioc-unit have modules which support that.
Just add

```
@Produces
@Mock
ClassName mockedObject;
```

and the framework will make it an injectable Bean.